# Can I use the columns tag in an HTML email

Tags: html, css, gmail, html-email

I am trying to create an HTML newsletter with three columns. I have tried using the columns tag:

```
<span style="-webkit-column-count: 3; -moz-column-count:3; column-count:3; -webkit-column-width: 160px; -moz-column-width:160px; column-width:160px; -webkit-column-gap:40px; -moz-column-gap:40px; column-gap:40px;">
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla a consectetur mi, a volutpat orci. Morbi id metus eget sem sollicitudin luctus volutpat ac sapien. Maecenas et metus maximus nisl aliquet consequat. Morbi rutrum justo id felis posuere tempus. Nulla sollicitudin sodales augue, eu varius urna fermentum at. Integer euismod suscipit nunc. Maecenas fermentum tristique libero in sagittis....
</span>
```

But it shows up as one paragraph in gmail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Columns is not supported in emails. 
See [this](https://i3.campaignmonitor.com/assets/files/css/campaign-monitor-guide-to-css-in-email-may-2014.pdf?ver=3969&_ga=1.202849426.263023362.1429384062) chart for a list of supported css properties.